# Do I need to add something to each mysql query in order to use the mysql cache?

Tags: mysql, caching, ubuntu

Ok so I have followed [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/speed-up-your-web-site-with-mysql-query-caching/) tutorial, and restarted mysql server. However, whenever I go to run a query and then execute the query again, I see hardly any performance gain. It's like a .200 sec gain which tells me that the cache isn't working.

Here is the cache config from the my.cnf file.

```
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 10M
query_cache_size        = 256M
query_cache_type        = 1
```

The way I am testing this is by running a Routine from the database. The routine consists of a simple SELECT statement that joins two small lookup tables.

```
show variable like '%query_cache%';
```

**Results**

```
have_query_cache    YES
query_cache_limit   10485760
query_cache_min_res_unit    4096
query_cache_size    268435456
query_cache_type    ON
query_cache_wlock_invalidate    OFF
```

Edit 1

To add, when I look at the Server Health using Workbench. The query cache hitrate remains at 0%.

Comment: Is the query exactly the same the second time and have any writes to the table occurred? There's nothing you need to add to your query for caching, though you can disable it by adding SQL_NO_CACHE.

Comment: Yes to the first, its a routine. No to the second.

Comment: Is the routine a `PROCEDURE` or a `FUNCTION` and what is the version of mysql?

Comment: The routine is a PROCEDURE and the version is  5.5.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is what solved my problem. I ended up enabling Remote Management in the MySql workbench. Then I went to the Configuration->Options File. It gave me an error stating that there was no section called [mysqld] and that it was going to add it. After that I went to the Performance tab, and noticed all of my checkboxes for the cache were unchecked. I checked all the values, MySql Workbench suggested I suffix my values with a K, M, or G when I input my cache values. After all of that I restarted the server and it was successfully caching my queries.

Not sure what all technical pieces changed in the config, but the workbench took care of everything for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should go back and specify your parameters in bytes. I know showVar looks correct, but those values are used within the system and it looks like you have spec'd the params in MBs, 1st code block above. Even though showVar looks good, the system may be seeing 10M and defaulting to 0.

Comment: I tried setting those values to bytes and still, no change in performance. The values were initially set as nM for the values, so I am assuming MySql has advanced that part of the config.

Comment: I would assume nothing and set them according to what is standard practice in just about most DB config. Even large ERP system params are in bytes still. That is core, very stable DB code that reads and works with those params and probably will never change. Just because showVar works doesn't mean it is going to cache properly. Have you changed any other peripheral config? Most caching problems like this can be traced to peripheral memory congfig/issues

Comment: Nothing outside of that config. My assumptions are based on a fresh install of MySQL...sooooo if they have it specified as nM then that is why I assume.

Comment: Wait explain peripheral memory config

Comment: Go in /etc/mysql/my.conf and tell me what the query_cache_limit equals. It is 1MB by default and basically means "Don't cache results larger than this number" Forget it I see above you have them in a file and not CL issued

Comment: Peripheral config is any config that would override your Cache params or prevent your cache from getting that chunk of memory. When adjusting cahcing params you usually check the main memory parameterization for the DB and OS to make sure you can actually get what you're asking for. You will not always get logging that describes the issue if it is outside the DB. I did not follow the tutorial you're using, but I do run and admin MySQL and have cahing setup according to the 5.1 manual. You might try to reduce the hard cache sizing to less than 3MB to see if it starts writing to cache.